# See own sent email IP address in webmail

Tags: email, ip-address, webmail

I have my webmail account (hotmail, which doesn't use private IP addresses for e.g.). How can I see what the IP address is of emails (under 'View message details') I send without cc'ing myself each time?

So, if I want to see the IP address of an email in my hotmail inbox, I click on 'View message details', to get the email header, which contains the IP address of the sender. However, if I do the same on emails in my sent folder, in the resultant email header, I cannot see anything to indicate my IP address. How can I see the IP address of emails that I have sent.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Amended it. Let me know if it's still no clearer.

Comment: Why do you care what ip address Hotmail/Outlook.com uses?  The actual address likely would depend on the actual server based on load that is used.

Comment: No I care about my IP address not the hotmail/outlook server IP address. It helps me get a rough idea of where I was when I sent an email, at home, at work etc.

Comment: @user3313178 The ip address is for the server of hotmail although it cant be ip address of hotmail.com you can view it by sending a sample mail to yourself and inspect the header of that.

Answer (score 1):

Everything isn't shared with you. Some of the details are kept by the Service provider for itself; for its ow usage, like Site Usage Stats etc.

So, I think they won't show you because you don't want to know where on the Earth you are. Sometime they would like to share the stuff you're permitted to have access to. Sometimes they won't.

But keep in mind, they do save everything and every data they get from the Client. Like his email program (Outlook, or a WebMail like Browser based Email program; Gmail, Yahoo! etc), IP Address, Date and Time, content and other OS related information. But it is upto them, what data they want to share and where they want to share it.

So, if you get the IP address of the user. They want to share you that your friend is at this location. But you don't get IP of yourself, but your friend would have it and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I presume what you are seeing with mails you received are the `Received` email headers. These look for example like this:

```
Received: from mx-out.stackexchange.com (mx-out.stackexchange.com [198.252.206.125])
    by sol.sotecware.net (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 11CA5140E5E
    for <me>; Sun, 28 Dec 2014 20:57:27 +0000 (UTC)
```

Mail transport agents (SMTP servers) put these stamps on each mail they receive, with the corresponding information. The crucial part is the “Mail transport agent“ (MTA). Because mails you sent and which are in the Sent folder of your mailbox have never seen an MTA. Mails you send are stored in the Sent folder by your client (or the webmailer), as a copy for you, for future reference, bypassing the MTA and directly accessing the mailbox (possibly via IMAP).